# Error 'Unable to create core' when migrating from solr 6.6 to 7.1

Tags: apache, solr

When I was migrating from solr 6.6 to 7.1 I got this error when I used my old managed-schema to create core in solr 7.1:

> bash-4.1$ ./solr create -c solr-testing -d _default -force
>
> WARNING: Using _default configset. Data driven schema functionality is enabled by default, which is NOT RECOMMENDED for production use.
>
> To turn it off:
>
> curl http://localhost:8983/solr/solr-testing/config -d '{"set-user-property": {"update.autoCreateFields":"false"}}'
>
> ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'solr-testing': Unable to create core [solr-testing] Caused by: *root* field must be defined using the exact same fieldType as the uniqueKey field (referenceID) uses: long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are changes in schema rules for 7.1.

Both uniqueKey and *root* must have the same data type. Once I changed root fieldType to long in managed-schema it started working.